# Session_end with cookies values

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

i`m trying to save data of users session ending in sql server with session_end method on global asax.

The problem is i`m saving user name in`cookies` values and when the session is ended it cannot reach to this values,refernce is null,

my question is in what way can i save the username that used by session that later i can throw it in `session_end` method.

Answer (score 0):

With user logged, in session starts.
At that time you can store value in cookies

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("userName");
Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = "fooName";
```

add cookie

```
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

Comment: The OP has stored values in cookies, but now wants to access them during Session_End - which will not work as there is no HttpContext.

Comment: there no in HttpContext,so my question how i can still access to them avoiding using cookies

Comment: so let me clear instead of "fooName" in my code you want to store sessionb value? or else?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store those values (also) in Session.

You can't access cookies from Session_End, because that event fires (by default) 20 minutes after the latest request has completed. So now you do not have an HttpContext anymore.

Do you really want to want that long before storing? That Session_End is not very dependable and only works for "InProc" sessions.

Comment: it`s not important to me if a value is taken from cookies,i`m trying to save datetime of exit and user name in sql server,if it possiable to do it another way i would do it